# Making Wordpress communicate between internal users and external non Wordpress database

Tags: php, database, wordpress, registration

I come to you because I'm a little bit lost in the implementation of a specific project...

Here is the configuration of my project: 
- A Wordpress website
- An external database outcome of the ERP "OpenERP", containing a table that contains hundreds of users.

In the Wordpress site, I need to create a form that will allow visitors to register in the external database. I also need the visitor to be registered as a user in the Wordpress website because in the near future, registered users will have access to particular content via Wordpress.

In addition to this, the client wants to continue to add new users via OpenERP. In this case, the new user will also need to be created "immediately" in Wordpress.

How can I do this?

Thank you in advance, 
Cédric

Answer (score 0):

I looked at "OpenERP" real fast, hoping there is an API. Instead I got confused on the product, just a little. There are fundamentally a few ways to go, here is the path I would explore :

Does "OpenERP" have any type of API for adding and polling users? This is the way to go. So when a new user is registered (created) in WP you can hook the creation via `wp_insert_user()` see : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user to get started. The hook would check with OpenERP for a user ("does exist") and create if new to OpenERP.

When OpenERP has a new user created, ideally you can send the details to WP, in any number of ways, to create a new user. Creation of the user can include forced PW creation, random PW, and even welcome emails. See `wp_create_user` via http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user. You could create an API, a hidden method, an adaptor, etc.

The unanswered question is "What features are available in OpenERP to talk to a remote site over http or the network?". Additionally, what security holes are you opening up and how do these concern the business?

Technically, creation of a password and account, in any professional situation, requires secure practices. SSL/https or possibly SOAP/WSDL to the rescue?

The bottom line : Wordpress has all of the tools, hooks, and features needed to accomplish your goals. What does OpenERP have to allow you to meet these goals?

One final concern, you could have a situation of user conflict - a user created in OpenERP and WP. Some extra logic may be needed, as well as a consideration of how you (as the programmer) choose to define what makes a user unique (email can change, making email a junky unique identifier), user names also can change (not in WP). If these attributes change (edited) you could have heartburn. The entire CRUD cycle needs to be accounted for in detail on both systems. A WP ID to OpenERP ID relationship table, with status, will probably become a requirement.

There are a few other ways to go, but above highlights how I would begin thinking about the problem.

Hope this helps.